# Graph theory: best algorithm to find combination of edges “directions”, where each node has at most one edge directed to it

Tags: algorithm, graph

I’m dealing with a graph where there are a certain number of nodes, and there are predefined connections between them which don’t have “directions” yet.

Problem is to give all the edges a direction (ex. If there’s a connection between A And B, give this edge the A->B direction, or B->A), in a way that no node is at the receiving end of more than one edge.

Examples:
For this model (A-B-C), A->B->C works, but A->B<-C does not work, as B is at the receiving end of more than one connection. Although A<-B->C works, as B is on the giving end of both of its connections.

I’ve tried loop detection, but the fact that these nodes can be arbitrarily connected to one another, there can be numerous loops which may or may not be directly attached to each other, I could not find a solution to make use of the information.

Number of nodes can be north of thousands, and connections can be many hundreds in my case. This also rules out brute force.

It is not guaranteed that there will be a definite solution, the aim of the algorithm is to find a combination where there’s the least number of connections causing nodes to have more than one edge pointing to them.

Comment: When you say *"connections can be many hundreds"*, I assume that means hundreds of connections per node. Is that correct?

Comment: No, overall. Each node typically has one connection, and at most 3 or 4.

Comment: Every node is connected to at least one other node, right?  i.e. connections >= nodes/2

Comment: In theory there are isolated nodes, but we can exclude them before running the algorithm, as they don’t affect the end result.

Comment: The objective function is effectively `count nodes where (count edges ending on this node > 1)` right? and you want to minimize that. You could use Simulated Annealing.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete algorithm, but given your description of the problem in the comments, I feel like these steps will probably bring the problem back into the brute-forcible range.

First, you should "trim" your graph. Any nodes of degree one should be pruned, with their connected edge being directed at the pruned node. Since no other edge can point to that node, we know that this choice is optimal. Rinse and repeat until all nodes remaining have two or more edges.

Next, as you mentioned, you should exclude any isolated nodes. You can actually extend this up to connected components of `size <= 3`. This is because for up to three nodes, your number of edges cannot exceed the number of nodes, so you can randomly assign one edge, and the rest will fall into place.

Now, what will remain are a bunch of large, highly-connected, connected components. You could actually do one more check and see if any of these form a single cycle (all nodes degree two) and then assign one edge randomly, but this is probably a fairly rare case. You'll probably just want to start brute forcing each of these independently. It'd probably be best to start from the nodes with the smallest number of edges first, updating the degree of nodes as you assign edges (and also pruning any degree one edges as before), backtracking as necessary.

Comment: Actually, after removing all tree-like branches in your first recursive step, so that no vertex has degree zero or one, if any remaining vertex still has degree three or more, then no edge labeling can meet the requirement. So given a possible graph, only a number of cycle subgraphs will remain.

Answer (score 3):

This is a continuation of the [answer by Dillon Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55083889/3386109).

After tree-like branches are removed, and simple cycles are resolved, the remaining graph has nodes of degree 2 or more. I propose that (for the purposes of analyzing the graph) all of the nodes of degree 2 can be removed.

Allow me to explain by example. In this example, when a node is represented by a number, that number is the degree of the node. When a node is represented by a letter, that node has degree 2. So the graph

```
3 - A - B - C - 4
```

represents a node of degree 3, connected to a chain of nodes of degree 2, connected to a node of degree 4.

The two ideal choices for this section of the graph are

```
3 -> A -> B -> C -> 4
3 <- A <- B <- C <- 4
```

These are ideal in the sense that each lettered node has exactly one incoming edge. I propose that these aren't just ideal choices, they are the ***only*** choices. Consider the first ideal solution

```
3 -> A -> B -> C -> 4
```

If node 4 has too many incoming edges, we can reduce its count by reversing the edge to C, giving

```
3 -> A -> B -> C <- 4
```

But that hasn't improved the situation, it trades *"too many edges into 4"* with *"too many edges into C"*. Subsequently reversing the edge between C and B resolves C, but breaks B. Keep reversing along the chain and eventually the connection between A and 3 is reversed, and we've arrived at the second ideal solution.

Which leads me to conclude that (for the purposes of analysis)

```
3 - A - B - C - 4
```

is equivalent to

```
3 - 4
```

So how is this useful in simplifying the problem. Consider the following graph:

[image]

When nodes A and B are removed, the remaining edge connects the top node 3 to itself, so that edge can be removed. Likewise for C and D. Which leaves a graph with a single edge. Choose either direction for that edge. Then complete the solution by choosing a direction for the simple cycle A-B-3, and independently choose a direction for the simple cycle C-D-3.

Here's another example:

[image]

In this case, removing A and B creates redundant edges between the remaining nodes. After removing the redundant edges, choose either direction for the edge. The direction of that edge determines the direction of the cycle 3-A-3, and cycle 3-B-3.

Comment: After reading your answer, I believe I have figured out the complete solution. I've posted it as a separate answer, since it really is completely different than my original.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure about adding another answer, but the answer [by user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55084600/6221024) gave me insight into what I believe is the complete solution, and I felt that it differs too drastically from the spirit of my original answer to include as an edit.

To recap, we have a few tools under out belt:

- We can prune nodes with a single edge optimally, repeating the process to completion
- We can assign a direction to any edge in a simple cycle (connected components with only nodes of degree 2) and the rest will follow (optimally).
- Nodes with two edges in more complex cycles can be temporarily ignored, as their edge directions will be assigned by higher degree nodes.

After reading the last point, the problem itself becomes a bit more clear. Once we have pruned the degree one nodes in bullet one, all remaining nodes have at least two edges. We can say for certain in the optimal graph that each of these nodes will have at least one directional edge pointing to them. As proof, since each node has at least two edges, but the connected component is not a simple cycle (else it would be eliminated in bullet 2), we have more edges than nodes. If any node has zero edges directed towards it, one of those edges could be reversed to reduce the number of conflicting edges, or to "free up" another node to have zero inward edges, to then do the same.

Armed with this knowledge, we know that the minimal number of conflicts (extra edges directed at nodes that already have an edge directed at them) equals the number of edges minus the number of vertices in our pruned graph. We can also conclude that as long as we manage to direct at least one edge to each node, we'll have an optimal graph, regardless of how we scatter the conflicting edges.

Originally I tried to draft an algorithm based on bullet three to accomplish this assignment, but it turns out the answer is actually a lot simpler than that even. The only way we can accidentally create a node with no edges directed away from it is by actively directing all edges away from that node. The solution is to pick a single edge in the connected component, and assign it a direction at random. Then, do a search (DFS, BFS, anything) outward from the node its directed at, assigning directions to the edges as you go, in the direction you that traverse them. Any node you reach will have an edge directed at it (the edge you took to reach it), and the root node has the edge you manually assigned to it.

In the end, this will produce a graph with the minimal number of *extra* edges directed at nodes. If you instead wish to minimize the number of nodes containing conflicting edges, solve the problem as stated above, and then form a subgraph of the nodes of degree three or more and their connecting edges. Solve for the minimal vertex cover of this subgraph, and then reverse the direction of the edges connecting nodes not in the minimal vertex cover yet containing conflicting edges, with those of the corresponding node in the minimal vertex cover.

Comment: Excellent. I actually had gone a little further than what I posted, but this definitely goes beyond anything that I had thought about. Performing the DFS/BFS without first removing the nodes of degree 2 is a brilliant insight. It eliminates all of the complexity in the solution. Well done.